# Prove that for each $w\in H$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,w\rangle=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space. Let $\{u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $H$ satisfying for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,e_n\rangle = 0$. Suppose that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|u_k\|\leq C$ for all $k\in \Bbb N$. Prove that for each $w\in H$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,w\rangle=0$.

---

**Attempt**. Let $w\in H$. Note that there exists a sequence $\{c_n\}_n$ of real numbers such that $w=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n\iff \lim_{N\to\infty}\|w-\sum_{n=1}^Nc_ne_n\|=0$ where $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ for $x\in H$.

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,w\rangle\overset{(1)}{=}\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n\rangle\overset{(2)}{=}\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k,\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N c_ne_n\rangle \overset{(3)}{=}\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\langle u_k,\sum_{n=1}^N c_ne_n\rangle = \lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\langle u_k, e_n\rangle \overset{(4)}{=} \lim_{N\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\langle u_k, e_n\rangle=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n \lim_{k\to\infty}\langle u_k, e_n\rangle=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n .0=0$$

I'm not sure the equalities are meaningful in $(1)$ and $(2)$. Could we interchange the limits in (4)?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say $(4)$ is the whole point.  Interchanging limits is false sometimes, but is OK under certain circumstances.  You have not explained any reasons that may make it true this time.  Those reasons may involve the unused hypothesis $\|u_k\| \le C$.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt fails because you cannot interchange the two limits without justification.

Hint: $|\sum\limits_{k=N}^{n} \langle u_k, e_n \rangle| \leq (\sum\limits_{k=N}^{n} |c_n|^{2})^{1/2} \|u_k\|$ since $\|u_k\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=N}^{n} |\langle u_k, e_n \rangle|^{2}$. Since $\sum |c_n|^{2} <\infty$, given $\epsilon >0$, we can choose $N$ such that above quantity is less than $\epsilon$. Now $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}\langle u_k, e_n \rangle \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ so we are done.